# dotTrace & TestDriven.NET: profiling tests

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, testdriven.net, dottrace

I've just installed the latest dotTrace (v4.0, evaluation) and I'm trying to profile the code by running tests using TestDriven.NET. From what I've googled out, this should be possible: "*Test With... dotTrace*" menu item should be visible, but it is not (only the standard ones provided by TD.NET). Has anyone had any luck with this?

I'm running VS 2008, by the way.

Comment: The unit test runner in Resharper is very nice, and integrates with dotTrace 4.0 (as well as dotCover 1.0) extremely well. Unit testing with this combo is very smooth and effortless.

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately it doesn't support Gallio/MbUnit tests out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem. My investigations showed that latest version of TestDriven.NET uses old version of JetBrains.dotTrace.Integration.dll which seems to be incompatible with the latest version of dotTrace. So waiting for new version of TestDriven.NET which will support new integration approach with dotTrace

Answer (score 0):

TestDriven.NET has integration with dotTrace 3.1 but doesn't have it for 4.0.

Comment: I have not seen official info from the TD.Net. So it is experimental result.